# SPFx gulp build fails - related to node-sass

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-sass, spfx

I have not worked with my SPFx projects for a few months. When I try to build now, I get the node-sass errors below. I don't recall making any changes to my environment. I tried downgrading my Node to 14, deleting package-lock.json and reinstalling all my node modules, and no luck. Does anyone have a fix for this?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_m
odules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\jeff\\source\\atsautomation\\InitiationForm\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-core-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\
node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\wh
ich\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\wh
ich\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\which
\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\
node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\wh
ich\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\wh
ich\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\which
\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jeff\\source\\atsautomation\\InitiationForm\\node_modules\\@microsoft\\gulp-c
ore-build-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_libr
ary="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jeff\source\atsautomation\InitiationForm\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: If you are using older version of SPFx, you probably need node 12, not 14

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that node-sass is deprecated:

```
npm -g uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

You also need to install gulp-cli, yo and microsoft/generator-sharepoint:

```
gulp-cli yo @microsoft/generator-sharepoint --global
```

Last thing, you need to do, but this time in POWERSHELL, in the project folder

```
gulp trust-dev-cert
```